# Checking if a string contains " or '

Tags: php

I am trying to do a input check and to seeif the string contains `"` or `'`. I have the `stringcheck` method that looks like this

```
public static function stringcheck($search, $string)
{
    $position = strpos($string, $search);
    if ($position == true)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
}
```

And this is how i am trying to check it

```
if(H::stringcheck($search8, $string) === true ||  $string[0] === "&quot;")
{
   $value++;
}
```

And the `$search8` look like `$search8 = htmlspecialchars('"');`. I should also mention that the $string is already sanitized.

Comment: @Jaykant the `$string` is already sanitized

Comment: `$string[0] === "&quot;"` can never be `true` as `&quot;` is 6 characters long.

Comment: Your function doesn't need to be any more complex than `public function stringcheck($search, $string) { return strpos($string, $search) !== false);`

Comment: @Qirel it should not even be an extra function for that matter imho

Comment: Indeed, I agree - its more work to create it than to just use that line natively. Oh well, if it works.. :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) returns the position of the match, which will be `0` if the match is at the beginning. But `0` is not `== true`.

I guess you are trying to work around that by extra checking `$string[0] === "&quot;"` which won't work, as I commented above: `$string[0]` is a single character, but `&quot;` is 6 characters long.

Comment: I said that my `$string` is already sanitized,

Comment: @AxwellVail You seem to not understand the answer. Nobody is stating or asking anything about sanitation.

Comment: Please read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php#refsect1-function.strpos-returnvalues). It explicitly states why this answer stands correct. To test if something is in a string you'd simply do `return strpos($haystack, $needle) !== false;`